# Why I can call base constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I want to inheritance Constructor from the base class.
I need it to print/make new objects.

```
namespace Zoo
{
    class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Weigth { get; set; }



        public Animal()
        {
            Name = "nieznane";
            Age = 0;
            Weigth = 0;
        }

        public Animal(string Name,int Age, int Weigth)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Age = Age;
            this.Weigth = Weigth;
        }

        public void Introduce()

        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}y, {2}kg", Name, Age, Weigth));
        }

    }// class end

    class Mammal : Animal
    {
        public string FurColour { get; set; }


        public Mammal()

        {
            FurColour = "nieznane";
        }

        public Mammal(string furColour)    
        : base( Name,Age,Weigth)  // there is the problem , this dont work
        {
            FurColour = furColour;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide actual numbers in `: base( Name,Age,Weigth)`

Comment: `public Mammal(string Name,int Age, int Weigth, string furColour)... `

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko - thank you there is more to code when I make another inherited classes but it is work.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide `Name`, `Age`, `Weigth`:

```
public Mammal(string Name, int Age, int Weigth, string furColour)    
    : base(Name, Age, Weigth)  
    {
        FurColour = furColour;
    }
```

Comment: and possibly, don't use same name for field/properties and parameters, so `Name` is the field and (e.g) `name` is the parameter See Microsoft naming convention [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-parameters)